# Crash on closing app in OS X 10.6 and 10.7 only

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

There is a bug which only happens to my app on OS X 10.6 and OS X 10.7: the app crashes on closing.

Explaining it better: when the user closes the app window (closing the app by consequence) the user see a crash dialog, which means that the app crashed while closing.

I've managed to get the help of an OS X 10.7 user to use a Debug version of the app, imagining it would produce a crash log easier to understand, however nothing changed.

```
Process: MyApp [838]
Path: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Identifier: MyApp
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: MyApp [650]

Date/Time: 2016-07-20 17:38:24.043 0200
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version: 9

Crashed Thread: Unknown

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000055 rbx: 0x0000000000000000 rcx: 0x0000000000000000 rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x0000000000000000 rsi: 0x0000000000000000 rbp: 0x0000000000000000 rsp: 0x0000000000000000
r8: 0x0000000000000000 r9: 0x0000000000000000 r10: 0x0000000000000000 r11: 0x0000000000000000
r12: 0x0000000000000000 r13: 0x0000000000000000 r14: 0x0000000000000000 r15: 0x0000000000000000
rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028 rfl: 0x0000000000010203 cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 0

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 316
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
```

From `Report Version` and beyond, everything is always precisely the same, except for the `task_for_pid`.

I know it doesn't affect the program use since it only happens after the program closure, however it surely must be a pain seeing a crash report every time you close an app.

Remembering that this bug doesn't happen with OS X 10.8 or superior versions, and that I'm using the 10.11 SDK.

Comment: This might help: [How do you debug an app for an older version of Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882296/how-do-you-debug-an-app-for-an-older-version-of-mac-os-x/15882805#15882805)

Comment: Using defines would just be the case if I knew what's wrong with the app. To set the SDK to 10.6 I would need to download the SDK and do a hack on Xcode to make it accept the old SDK, and in the end it would take an eternity to find the problem since there are lot of syntaxes which weren't possible back there, like `array.count` or `dictionary[key] = value;`. They would mistakenly be recognized has errors.

Comment: look for memory corruption.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to support six versions of the OS, you should be able to test and debug on all of them.

Comment: Unfortunately all my machines have El Capitan, and I can't downgrade them to 10.6 or 10.7 since I use both for programming in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. Despite OS X saying the crash belonged to my app, it wasn't exactly that. In my `applicationWillTerminate:` function I was running a binary throw NSTask, however that binary was compiled to be 10.9+ compatible, and that was causing the crash.

Rebuilding the binary with OS X 10.6 as the target version fixed the crash. Partially like @Willeke suggested, I installed Snow Leopard on my Mac (dual boot) in order to test my app in it, so now I will test it in Snow Leopard and El Capitan; the oldest and newest (while Sierra don't get a stable release).

I don't know why that bug didn't happened in OS X 10.8 as well; probably Apple has changed the way the system should behave to that kind of problem.